# How to open same activity on click of notification in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to open an activity lets say `SplashActivity` on notification click, irrespective of **click_action**.

Currently, with notification, I receive **click_action** to handle the UI, for an example

If the user is on the profile page and the back-end team updated his profile from the management console.
In this case app receives a notification with **click_action** profile_update.App checks for the **click_action** and refreshes the profile page.

Till now everything is fine but when the app is in the background and receives a notification with **click_action** profile_update and user click on notification - notification disappears from the notification tray and no any navigation performed.

I have declared `SplashScreen` that is to be opened on click of notification as follows:

```
  <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </activity>
```

Still user not navigated to `SplashScreen`.

Comment: post your handle notification code pls.

Comment: So you want to do the same action when your app is in background?

Comment: Hi @YogeshKatkar. A few formatting/writing tips that you will find useful. (1) paragraph breaks are best created using double-Enter, since a double-`<br>` has a different semantic meaning;(2) the personal pronoun is a capital I, with no exceptions;(3) questions are ideally asked free of chatty and conversational material, so that the resulting question may be useful to future readers; (4) code formatting using backticks is generally best reserved for code and IO, and is not a general highlighter;(5) please use a spell-checker like Grammarly. StackOverflow has its own way to format text.

Answer (score 0):

**While creating notificatio pass intent of activity**

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);    
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity .class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("Prayer time")
                    .setContentText("Its " + salatName + " time.")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)**Pending intent has the intent of activity you want to open **
                    .addAction(R.drawable.close,"Dismiss",snoozePendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Pass the intent of Activity in pending intent you want to open on click of notification

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Bilwal. It only works when click_action not mentioned in the payload, but it do not works if payload has a click_action.